# Dompdf generate pdf in Marathi Language

Tags: php, pdf, laravel-5, dompdf

I am using "barryvdh/laravel-dompdf" to generate PDF in Laravel.

PDF are getting generated, But I want to add new font "Shivaji" (For Marathi Language). But it showing "?" instead.

```
    @font-face {
      font-family: 'Shivaji01';
      font-style: normal;
      font-weight: 700;
      src: url(../../public/fonts/shivaji/Shivaji01.ttf) format('truetype');
   }

   body{
     font-family: 'Shivaji01';
   }
```

[image: Generated PDF Sample]

How we can generate PDF using this Font?

Thanks in Advance